# all email to gmail and G suite going to spam from root domain because of mistake made with subdomain

Tags: email, email-server, gmail

I'm trying to help someone who uses Outlook for outgoing mail for their root domain, `example.com`, and then they set up mailgun for `mg.example.com`.

They made a bad judgment call and sent to an old list that hadn't been sent to in over a year, resulting in high bounces.

Now ALL the email they send from the **root domain** to gmail and G Suite users goes to the junk folder. They realize the bulk email send was a mistake and won't ever do it again. It's only two users using outlook for outgoing email and they now just need their ordinary email to work. They don't plan to do any more bulk sending.

They deleted `mg.example.com` then they submitted this [Google Form](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery) to try to get the issue resolved with Google. It's been over 48 hours (the time Google indicates) yet the emails are still going to spam.

My hypothesis on why the problem isn't resolved is that they only submitted the root domain in the form to Google, not the `mg.example.com`. I think that perhaps they should re-create the `mg.example.com`and its mx records and submit the form again?

Also, they skipped one the fields in the form to submit to Google, which they said they skipped because it wasn't required. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem as well as maybe Google wants every field filled out. This is the question they skipped.

> Are you able to ping any/all of the servers listed in the MX record?
>   Please include the results of your ping tests. To ping servers listed
>   in the MX record, use the command: 'ping gsmtp185.google.com' in all
>   platforms. (Replace 'gsmtp185.google.com' with the results from the
>   DNS MX lookup.)

What's the best way to resolve this problem and get their day-to-day email Inboxed as it was before the mistake they made? Thank you.

Comment: Submitting the form doesn't mean Google will necessarily do anything. It's more reliable to simply have people click "Not Spam" on the afflicted messages.

Comment: Thanks. They have to contact every Gmail and G Suite user they interact with to do this or just a certain number to reach a threshold?

Also, was that even the right form? The form asks a lot of questions that are very precisely about the deliverability that's bounce/not bounce, rather than inbox placement.

Comment: If Google really hated your mail they'd reject it outright, rather than throwing it in Spam. The number of times someone has to click Not Spam is going to be closely related to the number of times someone clicked Spam on a previous message, and unfortunately will probably be much larger than that number. But regular correspondents can add your email addresses to their Gmail contacts, which will get your mail delivered virtually every time.

Comment: Just spontaneously their email started going to gmail inboxes. It must have simply been they didn't wait long enough. The problem appears to be solved. I asked if the 48 hours was up when I first talked to them and they said I think so and so it was a bit vague. But alls well that ends well. This basically a good organization that made one dumb mistake, frankly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for your input on this. Most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, in this case, was to wait the full 48 hours after submitting the Google form before thinking the form didn't work. Google fixed the problem on schedule.